# stat() get group name is root

Tags: c

I have a file src.tar.gz whoes owner and group  are named "src".
When I run test.c compiled with name "test" (permission: -rwsr-xr-x  owner:root group:staff)

The way I run it:
I am running it as group member under "src" group. 
But I run "test" as root since "test" permission is -rwsr-xr-x

Question:
Why did result come out like this? is the src.tar.gz group should be "src"?

Output:

```
Error: my group: src
Error: src.tar.gz group is root
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <grp.h>

void main(int ac, char **args) {

        const char *ERR_MSG_FORMAT = "%s: %s %s.\n";
        char *ptr_source_file = "src.tar.gz";
        struct stat src_stat;
        gid_t  src_gid, my_gid;

        int i = stat(ptr_source_file, &src_stat);
                my_gid = getgid();
                struct group *cur_gr = getgrgid(my_gid);
                fprintf(stderr, ERR_MSG_FORMAT, "Error", "my group: ", cur_gr->gr_name);

                src_gid = src_stat.st_gid;
                struct group *src_gr = getgrgid(src_gid);
                fprintf(stderr, ERR_MSG_FORMAT, "Error","src.tar.gz group is ", src_gr->gr_name);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Always* check return values of functions. Maybe `stat()` failed and you get `st_gid` 0 just because there was 0 before.

For me the program works good.